# How do i if/then in "mustache"-like underscore.js?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, mustache

I use underscore.js for HTML Templating, set to use mustache syntax, like this: `{{ }}`

I have this code:

```
 <% if (typeof(date) != "undefined") { %>
  <span class="date"><%= date %></span>
 <% } %>
```

How can I translate it to an underscore.js mustache-style template, using `{{ }}`?

Comment: You should lease the logic outside of the template and only render .date if typeof(date) != "undefined  in your view, templates should be treated as pass through only.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use:

```
    _.templateSettings = {
      evaluate : /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
      interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
    };
```

Then instead of  `<%= … %>` use `{{ … }}` and instead of  `<% … %>` use `{[ … ]}`

Comment: why used `([\s\S]+?)` instead of `(.+?)` as in the example from the `underscore.js` documentation?  any reason?

Comment: @simon `[\s\S]` is a common regex pattern that will match ANY character. The `.` in regex doesn't match newline characters. The regex engine made available to JavaScript doesn't provide a way to make `.` match newlines (as you can with other regex engines). More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Answer (score 1):

http://handlebarsjs.com/ is mustache with logic, partials, helpers & context.
It can also be precompiled. A must IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#date}}
<span class="date">{{date}}</span>
{{/date}}
```

Comment: this dont really work for me! TheSifter work outside Template! but i still looking for an inside Template working method!! Thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

just include this code after append underscore

```js
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate:/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Comment: Already Done! my question ist about the use of if ... then ... else! Thank you